# How to expose child id to parent using angualr

Tags: angular

I have the following code which using Material UI for toolbar with left menu:

```
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color='primary'>
      <button
        type='button'
        aria-label='Toggle sidenav'
        mat-icon-button
        (click)='leftmenu.toggle()'>
        <mat-icon aria-label='Side nav toggle icon'>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>Tool Bar</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>

    

    <mat-sidenav #leftmenu class=”sidenav” fixedInViewport
               mode="side" opened="true">
    <mat-toolbar><div class="logo"></div></mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink='/dashboard/home'>Home</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink='/dashboard/home2'>Home2</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
```

#leftmenu been used by button toggle, i would like to encapsulate the left menu into

```
 <app-leftmenu #leftmenu></app-leftmenu>
```

app-leftmenu contains the following:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-leftmenu',
  templateUrl: './leftmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./leftmenu.component.scss']
})
export class LeftmenuComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('drawer') drawer: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggle() {
    <?????????????>
  }
}
```

leftmenu.component.html contains the following:

```
<mat-sidenav #drawer class=”sidenav” fixedInViewport
             mode="side" opened="true">
  <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
  <mat-nav-list>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink='/home'>First Page</a>

  </mat-nav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
```

How can I toggle the #drawer inside the toggle function? / is there any other way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `opened` attribute with an internal boolean value.

```html
<mat-sidenav class=”sidenav” fixedInViewport
             mode="side" [opened]="isOpen">
  <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
  <mat-nav-list>
    <a mat-list-item routerLink='/home'>First Page</a>

  </mat-nav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
```

in the component change the value of that boolean on toggle.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-leftmenu',
  templateUrl: './leftmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./leftmenu.component.scss']
})
export class LeftmenuComponent implements OnInit {

  isOpen: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

---

another approach would be to use the API https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api

call `close` or `open` on drawer.
For that you should use the correct type in the ViewChild:

```js
@ViewChild('drawer') drawer: MatDrawer;

...

this.drawer.open();
```